# Parse date to something mysql understands?

Tags: powershell

I have a date that is a string: April 19, 2014 and I'm trying to turn it into something Mysql will understand. I tried this and it didn't work.

```
[datetime]::ParseExact("April 19, 2014", "yyyy/MM/dd", $null)
```

EDIT: I found one that works:

```
$date = "April 19, 2014"
$date = get-date $date -format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
```

Comment: Please don't put solution in your question. Add a self-answer then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Your date/time format string needs to match the input format:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact("April 19, 2014", "MMMM d, yyyy", $null)
```

Example output:

```
PS C:\> [datetime]::ParseExact("April 19, 2014", "MMMM d, yyyy", $null)

19 April 2014 00:00:00



PS C:\> [datetime]::ParseExact("April 1, 2014", "MMMM d, yyyy", $null)

01 April 2014 00:00:00
```